# How to find the roots of this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the intercepts of:

$$y = 2 + 3x^2 - x^3$$

I have that the $y$-intercept is at $y=2$ so the point $(0,2)$ is on the graph.

But I'm having trouble finding the $x$-intercept. Factored, I have this equation:

$$3x^2 - x^3 = -2$$

$$x^2(3-x) = -2$$

Where can I go from here? Is there a simple way to do this by hand?

Same goes for this equation. What are the $x$-intercepts?

$$y = x^4 - 8x^2 + 8$$

I can't use the quadratic formula here right?

Comment: No, there is no simple way of doing it by hand, unless you apply [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method).

Comment: @MathFacts If $x=1$ then $y=4$. Why do you say that $x=1$ is a root?

Comment: Find all the *potential* roots by dividing the constant by the highest degree coefficient. Then test (synthetic division), then factor to a quadratic.

Comment: $x=1$ is not a root

Comment: You can use intermediate value theorem: $y(3)=2$, $y(4)=-14$ so there is a root between $3$ and $4$

Comment: The second equation is easy, substitute $u=x^2$ and solve as quadratic equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second equation:$$y=x^4-8x^2+8$$ let $A=x^2$.

$$y=x^4-8x^2+8\implies y=A^2-8A+8$$

$y=A^2-8A+8$ is in quadratic form, you can solve it like a quadratic equation.

Once you find the value of $A$, substitute $A$ for $x^2$, to find the possible values of $x$.

Step By Step. Solve for $A$ in:

$$0=A^2-8A+8$$

What do you get?

> $$A=4\pm\sqrt{16-8}=4\pm2\sqrt 2$$
>  Substituting $x^2$ for $A$, you get:
> $$x^2=4\pm2\sqrt 2$$
> $$x=\pm\sqrt{4\pm2\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

For the first by hand you must refer to the [depressed cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method) formula.

For the second just take $x^2=t$ to reduce to a quadratic equation.

Comment: Why downvoters dislike the good old method? There is some other clever solution?

Comment: Maybe they wanted an explicit solution like $1+2\cosh\left(\frac13\cosh^{-1}2\right)$.